# How can I pass subclass to proc expecting argument of parent type?

Tags: nim-lang

It's possible to manually convert `seq[Child]` to `seq[Parent]` but maybe there's a better option?

```
type
  ParentRef = ref object of RootObj
    a: int

  ChildRef = ref object of ParentRef
    b: int
  
let parents = @[ParentRef()]
let children = @[ChildRef()]

proc process(list: seq[ParentRef]): void = discard list
process(parents)
process(children) # <== error
```

Comment: ``map`` isn't a generic, so annotating it with types isn't meaningful.  It's possible to cast Child to Parent if they are ``ref objects`` e.g process(children.mapIt(it.Parent))

Comment: @shirleyquirk thanks, my bad I intended to use `ref`, updated the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nim has a stronger type system than many, by default it only implicitly converts types according to [these rules](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#type-relations-convertible-relation).

We can see there that a sub-class is convertible to its superclass,
but `seq[type1]` is only convertible to `seq[type2]` if `type1==type2`, i.e. they are identical, not subtypes.

To add another implicit conversion relationship, one defines a type-converter, either case by case:

```
converter seqChildToSeqParent(c:seq[ChildRef]):seq[ParentRef]= c.mapIt(it.ParentRef)
```

or generically for any subtype:

```
converter toSeqParent[T:ParentRef](x:seq[T]):seq[ParentRef]= x.mapIt(it.ParentRef)
```

With one of those converters defined, the compiler will convert for you automatically, and call to `process(children)` will compile and run.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the better option is to use a [generic proc](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#generics)?

```
type
  Parent = object of RootObj
    a: int
  Child = object of Parent
    b: int
  
let parents = @[Parent(a: 2)]
let children = @[Child(a: 3, b: 5)]

proc process[T: Parent](list: seq[T]): void =
  echo repr(list)
  echo "Accessing generic attribute a: ", list[0].a

process(parents)
process(children)
```

In fact, if you don't add the `T : Parent` restriction that `proc` will work for anything as long as the compiler finds all the fields it wants on the type:

```
type
  Parent = object of RootObj
    a: int
  Child = object of Parent
    b: int

  FooBar = object of RootObj
    a: int
    bar: string
  
let parents = @[Parent(a: 2)]
let children = @[Child(a: 3, b: 5)]
let foobars = @[FooBar(a: 42, bar: "Yohoo")]

proc process[T](list: seq[T]): void =
  echo repr(list)
  echo "Accessing generic attribute a: ", list[0].a

process(parents)
process(children)
process(foobars)
```